# Добавить свойство объекту $scope, чтобы его значение отображалось с помощью ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-app="shifts_app" 
         ng-controller="shifts_contr">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time begin</th>
                <th>Time end</th>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="shift in shifts">
                <td >{{shift.workshiftDate}}</td>
                <td>{{shift.timeBegin}}</td>
                <td>{{shift.timeEnd}}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<script >
    var appl = angular.module('shifts_app',[]);
    appl.controller('shifts_contr', function($scope){
        //  ${shifts} - это объект, получаемый от сервера, и который
        // содержит три свойства: workshiftDate, timeBegin и timeEnd
        var json = JSON.parse('${shifts}');
        $scope.shifts = json.shifts;

    });
</script>
```

Нужно добавить свойство объекту $scope.shifts, например, duration, так, чтобы его значение могло быть отражено в tr ng-repeat="shift in shifts",

как-нибудь так:

```
<tr ng-repeat="shift in shifts">
                <td >{{shift.workshiftDate}}</td>
                <td>{{shift.timeBegin}}</td>
                <td>{{shift.timeEnd}}</td>
                <td>{{shift.duration}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Как это возможно сделать?

Comment: пройтись в цикле по `$scope.shifts` и добавить в каждый элемент нужное поле. и последняя разметка будет отлично работать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.shifts.push({'duration' : 143});
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем ответившим. Разобрался.
Получил правильные ответы на свой вопрос, просто сам вопрос неправильно сформулировал. Дело в том, что ${shifts} это не объект, а МАССИВ (список) объектов.

И вот что получилось:

```
var appl = angular.module('shifts_app',[]);
    appl.controller('shifts_contr', function($scope){
        var json = JSON.parse('${shifts}'); 
        $scope.shifts = json.shifts;
        /* 
            здесь $scope.shifts - это тот самый Iterable<Shift> shifts, 
            который приходит с сервера.
            Этот объект на сервере формируется методом getAll контроллера:

                @RequestMapping(value = "/getAll")
                String getAll(Model model){
                Iterable<Shift> shifts = repository.getAllWorkshifts();
                model.addAttribute("shifts", getStringAsJson(shifts));
                return "viewResult";
            }

            и передается клиенту в формате JSON в виде '${shifts}'.
        */

        /*
            1. Обходим Iterable<Shift> shifts
                Здесь shift - это каждый объект Shift, входящий в Iterable<Shift> shifts
        */
        for (var shift in $scope.shifts){
        /*  
            2. Теперь обходим во вложенном цикле свойства объекта $scope.shifts [shift]
              Здесь prop - это каждое свойство объекта $scope.shifts [shift] 
              (само prop в данном случае не понадобится, а вложенный
                цикл используется только чтобы получить значения свойств,
                необходимых в качестве аргументов функции getDuration(timeBegin, timeEnd))
        */  
            for (var prop in $scope.shifts [shift]){

            /*
                3. Находим значения свойств "timeBegin" и "timeEnd":
            */
                var timeBegin = $scope.shifts [shift]["timeBegin"];
                var timeEnd = $scope.shifts [shift]["timeEnd"];


            /*
                4. Добавляем объекту новое свойство duration, и определяем, что значение
                  этого свойства вычисляется функцией getDuration(timeBegin, timeEnd)
            */
                $scope.shifts[shift].duration = getDuration(timeBegin, timeEnd);
            }
        }
    });


    function getDuration(timeBegin, timeEnd){
        //конвертируем строки в дату
        var dateBegin = new Date(
                                    timeBegin.slice(6, 10),
                                    timeBegin.slice(3, 5) - 1,
                                    timeBegin.slice(0, 2),
                                    timeBegin.slice(11, 13),
                                    timeBegin.slice(14, 16)
                                );
        var dateEnd = new Date(
                                    timeEnd.slice(6, 10),
                                    timeEnd.slice(3, 5) - 1,
                                    timeEnd.slice(0, 2),
                                    timeEnd.slice(11, 13),
                                    timeEnd.slice(14, 16)
                                );

        //вычисляем разницу в минутах
        var durationInMinutesBlank = (dateEnd.getTime() - dateBegin.getTime()) 
                                        / 
                                    (1000 * 60);
        //формируем строковое представление разницы в часах
        var durationInHours =       Math.floor(durationInMinutesBlank / 60);
        //формируем строковое представление разницы в минутах
        var durationInMinutes =         Math.round(durationInMinutesBlank - (durationInHours * 60));
        var duration = durationInHours + ":" + durationInMinutes;
        return duration;
    }
```